# Global constructor call not in .init_array section

Tags: c++, gcc, constructor

I'm trying to add global constructor support on an embedded target (ARM Cortex-M3).
Lets say I've the following code:

```
class foobar
{
    int i;

public:
    foobar()
    {
        i = 100;
    }

    void inc()
    {
        i++;
    }
};

foobar foo;

int main()
{
    foo.inc();
    for (;;);
}
```

I compile it like this:

```
arm-none-eabi-g++ -O0 -gdwarf-2 -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -c foo.cpp -o foo.o
```

When I look at the .init_array section with objdump it shows the .init_section has a zero size.

I do get an symbol named `_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii`.
When I disassemble the object file I see that the global construction is done in the static_initialization_and_destruction symbol.

Why isn't a pointer added to this symbol in the .init_section?

Comment: You don't think gcc is smart enough to 1) see that the value is 100, or 2) see that the value is just incremented but never used?

Comment: @Bo Persson: That's why I added the -O0 option, so gcc won't optimize that out.

Answer (score 29):

I know it has been almost two years since this question was asked, but I just had to figure out the mechanics of bare-metal C++ initialization with GCC myself, so I thought I'd share the details here. There turns out to be a lot of out-of-date or confusing information on the web. For example, the oft-mentioned `collect2` wrapper does not appear to be used for ARM ELF targets, since its arbitrary section support enables the approach described below.

First, when I compile the code above with the given command line using Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2012.09-63, I do see the correct `.init_array` section size of 4:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-objdump -h foo.o

foo.o:     file format elf32-littlearm

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
...
 13 .init_array   00000004  00000000  00000000  0000010c  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, DATA
...
```

When I look at the section contents, it just contains 0:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-objdump -j .init_array -s foo.o
Contents of section .init_array:
 0000 00000000                             ....
```

However, there is also a relocation section that sets it correctly to `_GLOBAL__sub_I_foo`:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-objdump -x foo.o
...
RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.init_array]:
OFFSET   TYPE              VALUE
00000000 R_ARM_TARGET1     _GLOBAL__sub_I_foo
```

In general, `.init_array` points to all of your `_GLOBAL__sub_I_XXX` initializer stubs, each of which calls its own copy of `_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii` (yes, it is multiply-defined), which calls the constructor with the appropriate arguments.

Because I'm using `-nostdlib` in my build, I can't use CodeSourcery's `__libc_init_array` to execute the `.init_array` for me, so I need to call the static initializers myself:

```
extern "C"
{
    extern void (**__init_array_start)();
    extern void (**__init_array_end)();

    inline void static_init()
    {
        for (void (**p)() = __init_array_start; p < __init_array_end; ++p)
            (*p)();
    }
}
```

`__init_array_start` and `__init_array_end` are defined by the linker script:

```
. = ALIGN(4);
.init_array :
{
__init_array_start = .;
KEEP (*(.init_array*))
__init_array_end = .;
}
```

This approach seems to work with both the CodeSourcery cross-compiler and native ARM GCC, e.g. in Ubuntu 12.10 for ARM. Supporting both compilers is one reason for using `-nostdlib` and not relying on the CodeSourcery CS3 bare-metal support.

Comment: I don't know if things have changed since Feb 2013, but I found that I had to treat `__init_array_start` and `__init_array_end` as function pointers, not pointers to function pointers:

    typedef void (*InitFunc)(void);

    extern InitFunc __init_array_start;
    extern InitFunc __init_array_end;

    InitFunc* pFunc = &__init_array_start;
    for ( ; pFunc < &__init_array_end; ++pFunc )  {
        (*pFunc)();
    }

Comment: @Timma, there are a couple of mistakes in your code. It compiles when changed to `typedef void (*InitFunc)(void); extern InitFunc __init_array_start; extern InitFunc __init_array_end; InitFunc *pFunc = &__init_array_start; for ( ; pFunc < &__init_array_end; ++pFunc ) { (*pFunc)(); } `.

Comment: Question [understanding the __libc_init_array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265295/understanding-the-libc-init-array) provides a clearer code which makes use of an array of pointers to function. And it works.

Comment: @lorcap Looks like my asterisks got interpret as markdown. As you can see, some of my text is italicised. That just so happens to be exactly where I would have typed asterisks. Sorry about that, don't know how I didn't see it. Perhaps there was an SO update to comment formatting?

Answer (score 4):

Timmmm,

I just had the same issue on the nRF51822 and solved it by adding KEEP() around a couple lines in the stock Nordic .ld file:

```
KEEP(*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
KEEP(*(.init_array))
```

While at it, I did the same to the fini_array area too.  Solved my problem and the linker can still remove other unused sections...

Answer (score 3):

You have only produced an object file, due to the -c argument to gcc. To create the .init section, I believe that you need to link that .o into an actual executable or shared library. Try removing the -c argument and renaming the output file to "foo", and then check the resulting executable with the disassembler.

Comment: When I do that I still have the same issue.

Comment: OK, so with the caveat that I know essentially nothing about ARM, I would say that it means that you have another step to perform in implementing support for global ctor's and dtors for ARM. The fact that you are getting the _Z41_... symbol is encouraging, because it suggests to me that the .o file is correct. But clearly something isn't happening at link time. On x86 GCC, a link time process called collect2 handles merging all of the various static constructors into the .init section before handing off to ld (or something like that). I think linker support is your next step.

Answer (score 2):

If you look carefully `_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii` would be called inside global constructor. Which inturn would be linked in `.init_array` section (in `arm-none-eabi-` from CodeSourcery.) or some other function (`__main()` if you are using Linux g++). () This should be called at startup or at `main()`.
See also [this](http://www.state-machine.com/arm/QDK_ARM-Cortex_STM32-GNU.pdf) link.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where my constructors were not being called (nRF51822 Cortex-M0 with GCC). The problem turned out to be due to this linker flag:

```
 -Wl,--gc-sections
```

Don't ask me why! I thought it only removed dead code.

Comment: Many, many naïve "dead code" elimination algorithms remove *unreferenced* symbols / sections that can't contribute to *reachable output*... even if they're required for interrupt handlers, static global data structures, etc.  This might not be how gcc works, but it's a common gotcha.  Try also link-time optimization `-flto -O4` under gcc and clang to see what happens.

Comment: It removes dead code. If there's a global object that nobody ever references, is its constructor call dead code or not? Practically nobody will ever call into that object...

Comment: @dascandy Did its constructor touch state or pass data to non-dead-code?  If so, then no it isn't dead.  Dead code is code *if eliminated* causes no changes in the behavior of the program.